# MySQL Search Distinct using joins

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have 2 tables: Computers and Alias. Computers contains an FK reference to Alias. A computer can have many alias's.

I'm trying to write a script that will remove the hostname (Everything before the first '.') portion of the name field in Computers and verify that there is an alias entry in the alias table.  I'm ultimately trying to generate a report that contains computers.id & computers.name where there is no match.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id,
                t1.name,
                t2.alias
FROM   computers t1
       INNER JOIN alias t2
               ON t1.id = t2.computer_id
WHERE  alias.alias <> 'hostname'
        OR alias.alias IS NULL;
```

My perl script already can parse 'hostname' from 'hostname.fqdn.com' and I can pass that as an argument, but I'm not really sure how to create such a report, or even if I am on the right track.

Any suggestions welcome

Comment: INNER join will only give those with a match. I would do left outer join, which also gives the records with no match. That way it's easy to filter them out

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [LEFT JOIN](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) instead of `INNER JOIN` and to extract name you can use string function `SUBSTRING_INDEX`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id,
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.name, '.', 1) AS name,
                t2.alias
FROM   computers t1
       LEFT JOIN alias t2
              ON t1.id = t2.computer_id
                 AND alias.alias = 'hostname'
WHERE  alias.alias IS NULL;
```